# why this list doesn't have a bullet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm using a list inside a dialog with jquery and my problem it's that bullets of each element doesn't appear this is the code associate.

http://jsfiddle.net/9J3gZ/1/

I don't see any problem with the code that's why i have the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of normalize.css (of js Fiddle) (line 16);

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/9J3gZ/2/ (without the normalize css checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

If you add CSS to your demo on JSFiddle, it works:

```
ol, ul {
    list-style:disc;
}
```

However, unchecking the "Normalize CSS" checkbox on JSFiddle will make it function normally.

Answer (score 1):

The normalize.css that is included (at least through jsfiddle) is using `list-style: none outside none;`

If you wish to keep the `normalize.css`, you can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {
    $("#dialog-modal").hide();
    $("#imageTAL").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal").html('');
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog( "destroy" );
        $("#dialog-modal").append(
          '<ul style="list-style:disc;">'
        + '<li>No debe contener cuatro dígitos iguales. Ejemplo: 00001, 33331.</li>'
        + '<li>No debe contener más de cuatro (4) números consecutivos, tanto al derecho como al revés. Ejemplo: 12341, 67891.'
        + '<li>No debe contener datos de la cédula. Ejemplo: C.I.:147258369, clave no puede ser: 25836).</li>'
        + '<li>No debe ser el año actual; ejemplo: 2011.</li>'
        + '</ul>'        
        );
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            height: 350,
            width: 400
        });
    });
}
```